# how to disable dynamic_snitch on cassandra 3.11.9+ dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold cassandra.yaml param

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Can anyone explain which value should be put in order to disable dynamic_snitch?
im not sure if 0 or high number (50+?)

```
I see this information on cassandra.yaml:
https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/conf/cassandra.yaml
# controls how often to perform the more expensive part of host score
# calculation
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100 
# controls how often to reset all host scores, allowing a bad host to
# possibly recover
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
# if set greater than zero, this will allow
# 'pinning' of replicas to hosts in order to increase cache capacity.
# The badness threshold will control how much worse the pinned host has to be
# before the dynamic snitch will prefer other replicas over it.  This is
# expressed as a double which represents a percentage.  Thus, a value of
# 0.2 means Cassandra would continue to prefer the static snitch values
# until the pinned host was 20% worse than the fastest.
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 1.0
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into [documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/operating/snitch.html#dynamic-snitching) that says:

> `dynamic_snitch`: whether the dynamic snitch should be enabled or disabled.

For some reason it's not documented in the `cassandra.yaml` but you can find it in the [source code](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/config/Config.java#L213).  So just set this parameter to `false`